# ODOO 9 Project Management - Task archive

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I wonder if anyone had used the 'Archive' option under 'Tasks' - Project Management, if so could you be kind enough to tell were do they go and how can I access them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field active will be set to `False` so just search for tasks on this field. There also is a default filter called "Archived" in the task search